# find links containing bold text using WWW::Mechanize

Tags: perl, mechanize

Suppose content of HTML pages is

```
<a href="abc.com"><b>ABC</b>industry</a>
<a href="google.com">ABC Search</a>
<a href="abc.com">Movies with<b>ABC</b></a>
```

I want to extract only links that contain bold text. How can i do it using WWW::Mechanize?

Output

```
ABC industry
Movies with ABC
```

I used

```
@arr=$m->links();
foreach(@arr){print $_->text;}
```

but this finds all URLs in the page.

Comment: Doesn't look like there's any way to retrieve the raw content after you've used `->links()` so depending on your implementation you could use another module to parse the HTML like `HTML::Parser`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without using extra modules that can parse the contents of the page, it's going to be difficult to achieve your goal with `WWW::Mechanize`. However, there are other modules that will allow you to achieve this very easily.

Here is an example using [`Mojo::DOM`](http://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::DOM), which uses lets you select elements as you would do in CSS. The Mojolicious distribution also contains [`Mojo::UserAgent`](http://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::UserAgent), so you could migrate your code over to Mojo fairly easily if you are not too tied to `WWW::Mechanize`.

```
# $html is the content of the page
my $dom = Mojo::DOM->new($html);

# extract all <b> elements that are under <a> elements (at any depth beneath the <a>)
# and get the <a> ancestors of those elements
# creates a Mojo::Collection object
my $collection = $dom->find('a b')->map(sub{ return $_->ancestors('a') } )->flatten;

$collection->each( sub {
    say "LINK: " . $_->all_text;
} );

# Use a sub to perform an action on each of the retrieved <a> elements:
$dom->find('a b')->each( sub {
    $_->ancestors('a')->each( sub {
        say "All in one: " . $_->all_text
    } )
} );
```

Here's a demonstration with a sample list of links:

```
<html>
<ul><li><a href="abc.com"><b>ABC</b> industry</a></li>
<li><a href="google.com">ABC Search</a></li>
<li>Here is <a href="#">a link 
    <span>with a span 
        <b>and a "b" tag</b> 
          even though
    </span> "b" tags are deprecated.</a> Yay!</li>
<li><a href="abc.com">Movies with <b>ABC</b></a></li></ul></html>
```

Output:

```
LINK: ABC industry
LINK: a link with a span and a "b" tag even though "b" tags are deprecated.
LINK: Movies with ABC
All in one: ABC industry
All in one: a link with a span and a "b" tag even though "b" tags are deprecated.
All in one: Movies with ABC
```

If you use `Mojo::UserAgent` instead of `WWW::Mechanize` your search can be even easier. `Mojo::UserAgent` can `get` a page (just like `WWW::Mechanize`), and the DOM of the returned page can be accessed using `$ua->get($url)->res->dom`. You can then chain your query above on this, to give the following:

```
my $ua = Mojo::UserAgent->new();
# get the page and find the links with a <b> element in them:
$ua->get('http://my-url-here.com')
   ->res->dom('a b')->each( sub { $_->ancestors('a')->each( sub { say $_->all_text } ) } );

# example using this page:
# print the contents of divs with class 'spacer' that contain a link with a div in it:
$ua->get('http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26353298/find-links-containing-bold-text-using-wwwmechanize')
->res->dom('a div')->each( sub { 
    $_->ancestors('div.spacer')->each( sub {
        say $_->all_text
    } )
} );
```

Output:

```
1 How to use WWW::Mechanize to submit a form which isn't there in HTML?
0 How to process a simple loop in Perl's WWW::Mechanize?
0 Perl WWW::Mechanize cookie problem
1 Getting error in accessing a link using WWW::Mechanize
0 How to use output from WWW::Mechanize?
-2 Use WWW::Mechanize to login in webpage without form login but javascript using perl
3 Perl WWW::Mechanize Web Spider. How to find all links
0 Howto use WWW::Mechanize to access pages split by drop-down list
0 What is the best way to extract unique URLs and related link text via perl mechanize?
0 Perl WWW::Mechanize doesn't print results when reading input data from a data file
```

There are lots of examples in the Mojolicious documentation in case this isn't immediately comprehensible!

For a helpful 8 minute introductory video to `Mojo::DOM` and `Mojo::UserAgent` check out [Mojocast Episode 5](http://mojocasts.com/e5).

Comment: Note that `$dom->find('a b')->ancestors('a')->each( sub { say "All in one: " . $_->all_text } )` is incorrect, because `find('a b')` will return a `Mojo::Collection` which doesn't have an `ancestors` method